# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/geo/Metric

Tags: spring-mvc, redis, spring-data-redis

Error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/geo/Metric 
> at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.(JedisConnectionFactory.java:93) 
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315) 
> at de.hybris.platform.spring.LazyInitOverrideBeanFactoryPostProcessor.forName(LazyInitOverrideBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:82) 
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)

Even Jedis 3.x has the same issue.

Spring Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Beans:

```
<bean id="jedisConnFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="6379"/>
</bean>

<bean id ="jdkSerializationRedisSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer"/>

<bean id="stringRedisSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>

<!-- redis template definition -->
<bean id="redisTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="jedisConnFactory" ref="jedisConnFactory"/>
    <property name="keySerializer" ref="stringRedisSerializer"/>
    <property name="valueSerializer" ref="jdkSerializationRedisSerializer"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to use Jedis 4.x you would need Spring 3.x. You need to drop to Jedis 3.x I believe. Although I don't believe the particular class you are getting a Class Not Found (Metric) which is Spring Data Commons has changed locations.

Comment: Same issue with below combination with 3.6.0  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>